# How can I update the marker popup by click the marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I was trying to update the popup by click event, but it seems doesn't work. I have read the official website's demo. They update by updating the geojson data, which I think it might not be efficient.

```
markers.on('click', function(e){
    console.log('marker-onClick', e);
    e.layer._popup._content = 'hello';
})
```

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to use `L.Marker`'s `setPopupContent` method:

> Sets an HTML content of the popup of this marker.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setpopupcontent

```
markers.on('click', function (e) {
    e.layer.setPopupContent(...);
});
```